# How to add header/columns to already existing pandas script

Tags: python, pandas, header

How do I add headers to the script below, using pandas? Headers/columns = Date,B1,B2,B3.

```
from random import randint
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
import csv

start = dt.datetime(1996, 12, 16)
end = dt.datetime(2019, 4, 2)

df = pd.read_csv('C:Users\GrahamFam\Desktop\Data Archive\Daily3mid(Archive).txt')

print(df)
```

Comment: You need to include a sample of your txt file, as well as your full code if necessary. At this point, it's unclear why you are importing most of those libraries...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean changing the column names? Because you can do that by:

```py
df = df.columns(['Date','B1','B2','B3'])
```

Hope that answers your question.